# Why do whips crack?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Whips have been discussed in a [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67771/why-do-whips-hurt-so-much) last year.
I wish to ask a further question on the subject. (I can not comment or reply to the previous question since I am a new member here and my score is too low.)

The explanation why a whip cracks, given by the top rated answer to the aforementioned question, is similar to the one given in the [Wikipedia article on whipcracking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whipcracking#Physics):

The answer says that the momentum (wave) moving down the whip is concentrated to a gradually smaller part of the whip (at the end, the whiptail), thereby making the speed of the moving part higher to conserve momentum. m*v is constant, m (mass of the moving part of the whip) decreases and therefore v increases. This is how the high (supersonic) speed of the whip end is produced, according to this answer.

The explanation given in the answer is, at least to me, similar to comparing the whip to the sliding hammer we use to remove the break pads (or ball bearings) in our cars. You set a weight in motion by pulling on it and and when it comes to a sudden stop at the end something happens. What happens in the sliding hammer is that the other end experiences a yank. But using the hammer, there is no "energy concentration" with e.g. supersonic speed like in the whip, involved. (To me the break pads would just be like the handle of the whip. The sliding weight of the sliding hammer would be like the wave travelling down the whip.)

What I do not understand in this explanation is thus the following:

In a whip, the momentum is moving down the whip, away from the person holding it. To neutralize this momentum (when the wave of the whip reaches the end) you would just need to pull on the whip's handle in the opposite direction. (force f during T (the period for the wavelength) f*t=momentum m*v). Nothing more would be needed to neutralize the momentum. I can not see how this answer explains the extremely high (supersonic) speed of the whip tail.

Comment: Couldn't a whip be considered a kind of lever?

Comment: @brightmagus I agree that a whip could be considered a highly intricate system of very many connected, spring-loaded levers. But how does it work ;)

Comment: or just a lever with moving fulcrum (from the handle all the way to the tip). If so, the question is: How the lever (really) works? And I mean not the equation, but the answer to: how (or why - a question so despised in physics nowadays) it produces the effect it does?

Comment: Here is an [essay](http://whip.creatingspeed.com) that explains the cracking of a whip as a "chain reaction of levers and blocks".

Answer (score 4):

The hammer is not a good analogue because it deals with diminishing distance, not diminishing mass ( which would enter $p=mv$).

You are correct that if you moved fast enough backwards from the handle you would neutralize the crack of the whip, except from the handle you can only transfer momentum to the whole mass of the whip, which means, to neutralize the end velocity the whole whip has to move backwards at supersonic speed, making the force your hand has to supply quite large. I believe that it is not doable. Maybe one could make an experimental setup with a machine pulling back the handle of the whip with enough force.

Edit: found a [nice study a](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/true-cause-of-whips-crack/)bout how the whip end makes the sound:

> Previous whip work (one of just three papers on the subject in the past century) had resulted in the puzzling observation that the sonic boom occurs when the tip of the whip is traveling at about twice the speed of sound. But if the tip were truly the cause of the crack, why wasn't the sound heard earlier, when the tip first reached the speed of sound? Goriely and McMillen's calculations have revealed the answer. "The crack of a whip comes from a loop traveling along the whip, gaining speed until it reaches the speed of sound and creates a sonic boom," Goriely says. He notes that even though some parts of the whip travel at greater speeds, "it is the loop itself that generates the sonic boom."

Comment: FWIW, if you had a huge moving mass on your slide hammer and a tiny mass at the business end, you could conceivably (momentum conservation) accelerate the tiny mass to supersonic speed. For fun, calculate the mass ratio required :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft sure, it is possible. Even the noise of banging things against each other at the microscopic level might be started by supersonic motion.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How can a small mass at the end of the sliding hammer accelerate to high speed? I thought that even if my break pads were very light and not stuck in the yokes, they would just come out with the same speed that I pulled the hammer weight.

Comment: @annav How does a hammer deal with diminishing distance?

Comment: All I am saying is that the boundary conditions are not analogous to the whip crack. A sliding hammer gets the impulse you give it and transfers it to where it hits. If it hits a mass much smaller than itself conservation of momentum will make the small mass move faster in proprtion to the ratio of the masses.

Comment: I must disagree with you annav and CarlWitthoft. Maybe I am wrong and then I will learn :) If a 10 kg sledge hammer or a one kilo hammer (both travelling at 5 m/s) hits a 10 gram marble, the marble will still never leave with more than 5 m/s. (I am not 100% sure about the figures, but:) All the momentum from the heavy hammer will not go into the marble, most stays in the hammer.

Comment: you must not have heard of momentum conservation then.

Comment: here is a video in space with momentum conservation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IYDb6K5UF8

Comment: @Ross Anna & Carl: OK 3 members contradicting me, so I must question my statement. Here are my computations: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4y3ronf8389227/DSC_0144_SledgeMarble.JPG (10 kg at 5 m/s hitting 10 gram at rest) I get that the 10 g leaves at 10 m/s. OK it is double the sledge speed, but very far away from "in proprtion to the ratio of the masses" or Ross' formula (giving 5005 m/s as I understand it) Please tell me where my computations are wrong.

Comment: @Ross Millikan; Do you mean v1 squared? I still get it to (5-(0.001*v2))squared which would be 25 + 0.000001*(v2squared) - 0.01*v2 / as in (a-b)squared = a squared + b squared - 2ab
 I don't see an error here. It is also not intuitive to me with speeds "in proportion to mass ratio" sending marbles supersonic.

Comment: @ycc_swe:  I confused myself about the CM frame.  It is moving with the big mass, so the small one has essentially the velocity of the big mass in the CM frame.  After the collision, the small mass turns around, so in the lab its speed is double what the big mass started with.  Your calcs are fine.  You do get a factor 2, but no more.

Comment: @Ross Millikan: Yes, not more than a factor 2. It is hard to use only that to explain the whip's super sonic speed.

Comment: @anna v: The link to the text "nice study" about whips leads to the same video as the one about momentum in space. I don't think that is the intention. I would really like to see the whip studies you talk about.

Comment: sorry for this, edited correct link in

Comment: @anna v: Thanks. I have seen the Arizona studies. It is an effort to describe. But still far from an explanation, as I see it. And one basic thing in my question: What Wikipedia (and the previous highly rated answer) says about momentum, I am not sure it is true. At least I do not understand it.